# assembleRelease version of react-native app crashes upon start

Tags: react-native, apk, deprecated

The debug version of the app I'm working on works.  However, when I build an apk for it, the app crashes immediately after I attempt to start it.

Here is the info/messages I receive when I install the debug version:

> > Task :react-native-fbsdk:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/Utility.java
> >     uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> >
> > Task :react-native-google-analytics-bridge:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  Note:
> >     /Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/node_modules/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/android/src/main/java/com/idehub/GoogleAnalyticsBridge/ConvertToWritable.java
> >     uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> >
> > Task :react-native-i18n:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java
> >     uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> >
> > Task :react-native-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/node_modules/react-native-picker/android/src/main/java/com/beefe/picker/PickerViewModule.java
> >     uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> >
> > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/android/app/src/main/java/com/someapp/tone/Tone.java
> >     uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/android/app/src/main/java/com/someapp/fitting/OVFitting.java
> >     uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> >
> > Task :app:externalNativeBuildDebug  Build somefittingjni x86 [1/2] Building CXX object
> >     CMakeFiles/somefittingjni.dir/src/main/cpp/somefittingjni.cpp.o [2/2]
> >     Linking CXX shared library
> >     ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libsomefittingjni.so
> >     Build somefittingjni armeabi-v7a [1/2] Building CXX object
> >     CMakeFiles/somefittingjni.dir/src/main/cpp/somefittingjni.cpp.o [2/2]
> >     Linking CXX shared library
> >     ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libsomefittingjni.so
> >
> > Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug  Unable to strip library
> >     '/Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi/libgifimage.so'
> >     due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI'. Packaging it as is.
> >     Unable to strip library
> >     '/Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi/libicu_common.so'
> >     due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI'. Packaging it as is.
> >     Unable to strip library
> >     '/Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi/libimagepipeline.so'
> >     due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI'. Packaging it as is.
> >
> > Task :app:installDebug  03:46:57 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config 03:46:57 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'randonnumber'
> >     : EOF hit. Read: -1 03:46:57 V/ddms: execute: returning Installing APK
> >     'app-debug.apk' on 'SM-G950N - 8.0.0' for app:debug 03:46:57
> >     D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'randonnumber'
> >     03:46:57 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'randonnumber' 03:46:57
> >     D/ddms: Reading file permision of
> >     /Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
> >     as: rw-r--r-- 03:46:59 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t
> >     "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk" 03:47:13 V/ddms: execute 'pm install
> >     -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'randonnumber' : EOF hit. Read: -1 03:47:13 V/ddms: execute: returning 03:47:13 V/ddms: execute:
> >     running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk" 03:47:13 V/ddms: execute
> >     'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'randonnumber' : EOF hit.
> >     Read: -1 03:47:13 V/ddms: execute: returning Installed on 1 device.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 29s 265 actionable tasks: 250 executed, 15
>   up-to-date

When creating an apk, I get the following warnings, but the apk still gets created:

> ```
> > Task :react-native-fbsdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac 
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/Utility.java
> ```
>
> uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> ```
> > Task :react-native-google-analytics-bridge:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac 
> Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/node_modules/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/android/src/main/java/com/idehub/GoogleAnalyticsBridge/ConvertToWritable.java
> ```
>
> uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> ```
> > Task :react-native-i18n:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac 
> Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java
> ```
>
> uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> ```
> > Task :react-native-picker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac 
> Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/node_modules/react-native-picker/android/src/main/java/com/beefe/picker/PickerViewModule.java
> ```
>
> uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>
> ```
> > Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac 
> Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/someapp/tone/Tone.java
> ```
>
> uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>       Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/someapp/fitting/OVFitting.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> ```
> > Task :app:externalNativeBuildRelease 
> Build somefittingjni x86
> [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/somefittingjni.dir/src/main/cpp/somefittingjni.cpp.o
> [2/2] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/x86/libsomefittingjni.so
> Build somefittingjni armeabi-v7a
> [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/somefittingjni.dir/src/main/cpp/somefittingjni.cpp.o
> [2/2] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi-v7a/libsomefittingjni.so
>
> > Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease 
> Unable to strip library '/Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/release/0/lib/armeabi/libgifimage.so'
> ```
>
> due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI'. Packaging it as is.
>       Unable to strip library '/Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/release/0/lib/armeabi/libicu_common.so'
>   due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI'. Packaging it as is.
>       Unable to strip library '/Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/release/0/lib/armeabi/libimagepipeline.so'
>   due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI'. Packaging it as is.

After those warnings show up. I get the following message(s):

> ```
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053d, entry index(1341) is beyond type entryCount(1320)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053e, entry index(1342) is beyond type entryCount(1320)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053b, entry index(1339) is beyond type entryCount(1320)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053c, entry index(1340) is beyond type entryCount(1320)
>
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053d, entry index(1341) is beyond type entryCount(1320)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053e, entry index(1342) is beyond type entryCount(1320)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053b, entry index(1339) is beyond type entryCount(1320)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053c, entry index(1340) is beyond type entryCount(1320)
>
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053d, entry index(1341) is beyond type entryCount(1266)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053e, entry index(1342) is beyond type entryCount(1266)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053b, entry index(1339) is beyond type entryCount(1266)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053c, entry index(1340) is beyond type entryCount(1266)
>
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053d, entry index(1341) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053e, entry index(1342) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053b, entry index(1339) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053c, entry index(1340) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
>
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053d, entry index(1341) is beyond type entryCount(1266)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053e, entry index(1342) is beyond type entryCount(1266)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053b, entry index(1339) is beyond type entryCount(1266)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053c, entry index(1340) is beyond type entryCount(1266)
>
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053d, entry index(1341) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053e, entry index(1342) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053b, entry index(1339) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053c, entry index(1340) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
>
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053d, entry index(1341) is beyond type entryCount(1320)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053e, entry index(1342) is beyond type entryCount(1320)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053b, entry index(1339) is beyond type entryCount(1320)
> W/ResourceType( 4289): For resource 0x0101053c, entry index(1340) is beyond type entryCount(1320)
>
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 10s
> ```

Why does the app run in Debug mode, but not when installed with the apk?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, then I connected the device to the Mac, checked the Log on androidSudio, and found the problem. Is the redefinition in the jsBundle file, and finally I found that the method in a js file is repeated, and then it can be packaged normally. You can try.